# Blender is ignoring materials

Tags: rendering

Blender is completely ignoring any materials This file is a new file and that cube is the cube you get when you first open a new file. I have not changed any settings or added any user preferences. For some reason the cube has no material.
Here is the cube in shading mode.
[image]

Here is the cube when rendered.
[image]
I have deleted blender and installed the new version yet I still face the same issue.
Is anyone facing the same problem as I am?

Also my file is missing some settings in visibility.
[image]

But If I change the rendering engine to cycles then it shows the materials. It seems that Eveee is causing the problem. THis was the same cube rendered in cycles
[image]

Comment: if you are sure you don't have a problem with your hardware/graphics card, please provide your blend file

Comment: The screenshot you show shows the world Properties instead of the Shader Properties. Also, try File<Defaults<Save Startup File

Comment: When I use Evee then it won't work but when I change it to cycles then it will work. I think this is an issue with Evee.

Comment: Also this file is the factory default file.

Comment: Do you have holdout or something on for the cube object settings?

Comment: No i don't have the holdout feature avaliable. I have seen a similar post to mine and they told the user to change their drivers to an older one.

Comment: AMD graphics card: https://developer.blender.org/T83920 ?

Comment: Thankyou so much Brockmann..